# Do I need to delete memory after using memcpy()?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-leaks, memcpy

I am trying to duplicate the contents of an array to another array with the limitation of using ONLY the memcpy() function.

Here's my attempt at it:

```
int source_array[3] = {1,2,3}; 
int destination_array[3];
memcpy(destination_array, source_array, sizeof(source_array) * 3);
```

Question is, do I need to follow up a delete[] to the duplicated array when closing the program to avoid any memory leaks?

Comment: `memcpy()` itself doesn't do any memory allocations.

Comment: You `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. You do neither `new` nor `new[]`.

Comment: Both source and destination arrays are allocated on the stack and will be automatically deallocated when then go out of scope.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy

Comment: Don’t use memcpy, use std::copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope!

You don't need to `delete` anything, because you didn't allocate anything using `new`.

---

Consider the following snippet:

```
int x[10];

void method() {
     int y[10];
     int *z = new int[10];
     delete z;
}
```

The first declaration, int x[10], uses static storage duration, defined by cppreference as: "**The storage for the object is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends**. Only one instance of the object exists. All objects declared at namespace scope (including global namespace) have this storage duration, plus those declared with static or extern."

The second one, int y[10], uses automatic storage duration, defined by cppreference as: "**The object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated at the end**. All local objects have this storage duration, except those declared static, extern or thread_local."

The third one, int *z = new int[10], is usually referred to as dynamic memory allocation. **Dynamic memory allocations should be freed explicitly**.